# Concern about "apt-get update" in production server

Tags: ubuntu, apt, automatic-updates

I have a server which is getting a bit outdated as I haven't updated it since a few months. I wanted to try cron-apt but first wanted to do it manually, so I issued a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

as a first step. Everything went ok but when I checked my apache error logs I got some messages like these:

```
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] exception 'MongoCursorTimeoutException' with message 'cursor timed out (timeout: 30000, time left: 0:0, status: 0)'
```

from users who were connecting to my server at that moment.

Please note that I haven't issued a apt-get upgrade yet, but I got a bit concerned that just updating the package db would affect some users, specially if I cron this to say once a day.

Only workaround I can think of is doing this at a off-peak time, but besides that obvious assumptions, is there any other tip you could give?

Comment: Describe the OS distribution, version, information about the hardware environment, etc.

Comment: It's a AWS micro instance using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why you should have a backup server.  Or at *least* a test environment that can pretend to be a server in a pinch.

1. Upgrade the backup server.
2. **TEST** the backup server.
3. Fail over to the backup server.
4. Upgrade the main server.
5. **TEST** the main server.
6. Fail back to the main server.

As for `apt-get update` messing with other stuff, it shouldn't be an issue but if you are on a low-power server (eg micro VM instance) it can run up CPU load and memory use which could slow down other programs.

Comment: My bet is that is all about the CPU/Memory Load.  Rebuilding the package databases is a relatively intensive process.

Comment: This is also why you shouldn't run anything production on a t1.micro.